# Image scaling inside div fails - background not following

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to fit an image into a div container, but it doesnt work. I have got a  complex div-tree on my page, that looks like this:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        <div id="c">
            <div id="d">
                <img src="http://public.media.smithsonianmag.com/legacy_blog/npg_portraits_nicholson_jack_2002.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
#a {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#b {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

#c {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 20px;
}

#d {
    width: 400px;
    background-color:yellow;
    max-height: inherit;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    margin: auto;
}
```

I want the image to be fitted into the blue container. It should also take care on the given div containers. Currently the black one does not fill till the end plus padding of the container.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxms2xvx/)

I hope someone is able to help.

Comment: Hello again :) [Do you want this](http://jsfiddle.net/101jkkw8/) ?

Comment: @misterManSam Post your answer

Comment: @misterManSam: giving c the height of 100% isnt what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a new concept for you. `box-sizing: border-box` incorporates the padding into the percentage width and heights automatically. The image no longer needs `position: absolute`.

The width and height of all the inner divs are controlled by the width on the `#a` container and their padding.

### New Demo

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#a {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
}
#b {
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px;
}
#c {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 20px;
}
#d {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
}
img {
 width: 100%;
 display: block; /* remove inline gap */
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
    <div id="c">
      <div id="d">
        <img src="http://public.media.smithsonianmag.com/legacy_blog/npg_portraits_nicholson_jack_2002.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Old Answer

- Remove `width: auto; height: auto;` and `padding: 20px` on `#c`
- Place `height: 100%` on `#c`

**Reason this happens** - The `height: 100%` of `#c` is affected by the padding on `#b` so any extra padding will blow up the height.

### Demo

```css
#a {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#b {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

#c {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
}

#d {
    width: 400px;
    background-color:yellow;
    max-height: 100%;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        <div id="c">
            <div id="d">
                <img src="http://public.media.smithsonianmag.com/legacy_blog/npg_portraits_nicholson_jack_2002.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Giving c the height of 100% isnt what i was looking for. I want the container just having the height of the fitted image plus paddings.

Comment: I have torn the whole thing down and rebuilt it from scratch. The paddings are now incorporated into the width and height. What do you think?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to tell exactly what you are trying to achieve!

Answer (score -1):

Here And try giving " #d" a height

```
#d > img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: but that is exactly, what i cannot do